# add selection listener to the rows of the jface tableviewer table without allowing multiple selection

Tags: java, eclipse, jface

I have a jface tableviewer and I need to implement a selection listener on the row, where on selecting a row a view has to be fired.
I have implemented it by:

```
viewer.getTable().addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() { 
 @Override public void handleEvent(Event e) 
 {  
  try {
       PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().showView("E2E_tab_view.view5");  
       }  
      catch (PartInitException e1) 
       {  
        e1.printStackTrace();  
        }  
      }});
```

But I face a problem of multiple selection with this. I actually dont want to allow multiple selection for the row but now i am able to select more than one row which is not required.

So could anybody help me to implement this. I need to allow a feature of either selecting a row or on click of the row view should be fired.

Comment: Is there any reason you have to use SWT.EraseItem instead of SWT.Selected?  The Event from SWT.Selected should be able to give you the item that was selected and you can de-select the others in the event block.

Comment: I agree with @Thomas that you should use the `SWT.Selected` event instead. As far as multi-selection is concerned see my answer instead.

Answer (score 4):

If your table allows multi-selection then you are probably creating it with the `SWT.MULTI` style bit and you should use `SWT.SINGLE` instead. The latter is the default for Windows; although this might be different on other OSs.